# WSO2 Mongo data service dynamic query parameter

Tags: mongodb, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, dataservice

i'm trying to create a mongo data service in WSO2EI. Currently I have this query, which gives me results based on componentId:

```html
<query id="find" useConfig="MongoDB">
      <expression>collection.find("{componentId : #}")</expression>
      <result outputType="json">{&#xd;"Documents": {&#xd;"Document": [&#xd;{&#xd;"Data": "$document"&#xd;}&#xd;]&#xd;}&#xd;}</result>
      <param name="componentId" sqlType="STRING"/>
</query>
```

But I need to enter the parameter(s) dynamically to be able to *.find* different results based on parameter name I provided, something like this:

```html
<query id="find" useConfig="MongoDB">
      <expression>collection.find("{fieldName : #} : {fieldValue : #}")</expression>
      <result outputType="json">{&#xd;"Documents": {&#xd;"Document": [&#xd;{&#xd;"Data": "$document"&#xd;}&#xd;]&#xd;}&#xd;}</result>
      <param name="fieldName" sqlType="STRING"/>
<param name="fieldValue" sqlType="STRING"/>
</query>
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to create multiple queries for each parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible! Try this (work for me).

```
<query id="wesites_find_param" useConfig="mongo_ds">
      <expression>websites.find("{#: #}")</expression>
      <result element="Documents" rowName="Document" useColumnNumbers="true">
         <element column="document" name="Data" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param defaultValue="name" name="par1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="par2" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
    <operation name="website_find_param_op">
      <call-query href="wesites_find_param">
         <with-param name="par1" query-param="par1"/>
         <with-param name="par2" query-param="par2"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
   <resource method="GET" path="/websitefind">
      <call-query href="wesites_find_param">
         <with-param name="par1" query-param="par1"/>
         <with-param name="par2" query-param="par2"/>
      </call-query>
   </resource>
```

Example,

- for componentId : "pippo" use `?par1=componentId&par2=pippo`
- for componentName : "proxy_hl7" use `?par1=componentName&par2=proxy_hl7`